# Remove columns that have less than 10 data

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 5000 columns and 1000 rows but a lot of data are missing. I'm interested only on columns that have at least 10 data. How to remove columns with less than 10 values? Thank you!

I tried:

```
miss <- c()
for(i in 1:ncol(test)) {
   if(length(test[,i]) < 10)
  miss <- append(miss,i)
 }
data2 <- test[,-miss]
```

Error in -miss : invalid argument to unary operator

Answer (score 4):

Take this example data:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1:5, NA),
                 v2 = c(1:5, NA),
                 V3 = rep(NA, 6),
                 v4 = c(1:5, NA))
df
```

```
  v1 v2 V3 v4
1  1  1 NA  1
2  2  2 NA  2
3  3  3 NA  3
4  4  4 NA  4
5  5  5 NA  5
6 NA NA NA NA
```

You can use `is.na()` inside `colSums()` to count the number of missing values in each column.

```
colSums(is.na(df))
```

```
v1 v2 V3 v4 
 1  1  6  1
```

Then keep variables according to a given threshold of missing values as follows:

```
df[, colSums(is.na(df)) < 5]
```

```
  v1 v2 v4
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4
5  5  5  5
6 NA NA NA
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case df[, colSums(is.na(df)) < 990] works well

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse`alternative:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  map_df(~sum(is.na(.))) %>% 
  stack() %>%  
  filter(values < 5)
```

outcome using @L-- data:

```
  values ind
1      1  v1
2      1  v2
3      1  v4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple to do using `dplyr` (using sample data provided by L--):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(where(~ sum(!is.na(.)) >= 5)) # change 5 to 10 in your code
```

**Output**

```
  v1 v2 v4
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4
5  5  5  5
6 NA NA NA
```